# Show 'All Records' Option

Tags: php, mysql

I've put together the form below that allows a user to retrieve database records from the date they select from a drop down menu.

```
<html>
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript">

function ajaxFunction(name)
{
var browser = navigator.appName;
if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
{
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("my_div").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","getrecords.php?dateoftrip="+name,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

function getquerystring() {
var form = document.forms['frm1'];
var word = form.word.value;
qstr = 'w=' + escape(word); // NOTE: no '?' before querystring
return qstr;
}


</script>


<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 14px;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form action="getrecords.php" method="get" name="frm1">

<table width="148" border="0">

<tr>
<td width="152"><p class="style1">Select a date from below</p>
  <div align="center">
    <?php
include("db.php");

$query="select * from finds group by dateoftrip";
echo '<select onchange="ajaxFunction(this.value)">';
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo "<option name='name' value=".$rows['dateoftrip'].">".$rows['dateoftrip']."</option>";

}
echo "</select>";
?>
  </div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<div id="my_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the php script which retrieves the records.

```
<?php
include("db.php");
$dateoftrip= $_GET['dateoftrip'];
$findname= $_GET['findname'];
$finddescription= $_GET['finddescription'];

$query="select * from finds where dateoftrip='$dateoftrip'";
echo "<table>";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Find Name : </td>";
echo "<td>".$rows['findname']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Find Description : </td>";
echo "<td>".$rows['finddescription']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

I'd like to extend the functionality a little if at all possible, by adding a 'All Records' option to the drop down menu which obviously returns all the records for the current user.

I've been searching for this for a few days now, and I haven't found an example where there is this added functionality.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps provide some guidance on how I may go abut this please.

**Amended Form Code**

```
<html>
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript">

function ajaxFunction(name)
{
var browser = navigator.appName;
if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
{
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("my_div").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","getrecords.php?dateoftrip="+name,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

function getquerystring() {
var form = document.forms['frm1'];
var word = form.word.value;
qstr = 'w=' + escape(word); // NOTE: no '?' before querystring
return qstr;
}


</script>


<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 14px;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form action="getrecords.php" method="get" name="frm1">

<table width="148" border="0">

<tr>
<td width="152"><p class="style1">Select a date from below</p>
  <div align="center">
    <?php
include("db.php");

$query="select * from finds group by dateoftrip";
echo '<select onchange="ajaxFunction(this.value)"><OPTION name="name" value="ALLRECORDS">'; 
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo "<option name='name' value=".$rows['dateoftrip'].">".$rows['dateoftrip']."</option>";

}
echo "</select>";
?>
  </div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<div id="my_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an option for the 'ALL' thing

```
echo '<select onchange="ajaxFunction(this.value)"><OPTION name="name" value="ALLRECORDS">All Records</option>';
```

---

Handle your query for the 'ALL' thing

```
if ($dateoftrip=="ALLRECORDS") {
    $query="select * from finds";
} else {
    $query="select * from finds where dateoftrip='$dateoftrip'";
}
```

On a side note you should look about `SQL Injection`, not using the '*' selector but typing the explicit name of attributes you search

Comment: Hi many thanks for replying to my post. I've tried your code for the drop dopwn menu and unfotunately I can't get the 'All Records' option to appear. I've amended my original post with the amended code. Could you possibly have a look at it please and let me know where I've gone wrong? Kind regards

Comment: You need to close the 'All Records' option ... the line should read: `echo '<select onchange="ajaxFunction(this.value)"><OPTION name="name" value="ALLRECORDS">All Records</option>';`